# Conditional XAML causes XBF generator error

Tags: xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to set the `Icon` property of `MenuFlyoutItem` on the `UWP`. As this is only available in contract version `4`, I wanted to use conditional XAML statements in form of the `IsApiContractPresent` statement. Doing this, I came up with this code:

```
 <MenuFlyout>
     <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open">
          <contract4Present:MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
              <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE1A5;"/>                                
          </contract4Present:MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
     </MenuFlyoutItem>
</MenuFlyout>
```

and added this line in the definition of my page:

```
xmlns:contract4Present="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,5)"
```

Sadly, Visual Studio is now not able to compile the project anymore, with this error message:

> The XAML Binary Format (XBF) generator reported syntax error '0x09C4' : Property Not Found

Strangely, the same errors comes up, when I use the minimal example given in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml)

```
<TextBlock contract5NotPresent:Text="Hello, World"
       contract5Present:Text="Hello, Fall Creators Update"/>
```

How can I solve this error? Or is this even a bug of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this functions is only available for `Minimum Build versions > 15063`. Otherwise, you must use version adaptive code, and not `XAML`.

Comment: Well. Don't forget to mark your answer after you've posted your answer. It will benefit for others when searching.

Comment: @Barry Wang: Yes, I had to wait two days to do this.